# Why don't hadrons form from quarks of all the same charge?

Tags: particle-physics, charge, standard-model, quarks, baryons

Why don't Hadrons ever form from quarks of all the same charge?  For instance you never see 2 or 3 up quarks together with no down quarks or vice-versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They *do* form, but don’t last long. [Delta baryons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_baryon) can have three up quarks (for the $\Delta^{++}$) or three down quarks (for the $\Delta^-$). These baryons are unstable and last only a few trillionths of a trillionth of a second.

Comment: Not sure I'd count something that can only exist for such a short time to be truly formed.

Comment: In my book, if it has been given a name and had its lifetime measured, it “formed”. In terms of Planck units, this is practically an eternity.

Comment: What are "planck units"?

Comment: By the way, the [Omega baryon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_baryon) with three strange quarks lasts a trillion times longer!

Comment: Planck units are the natural units for theories of relativistic quantum gravity, formed by setting $c$, $\hbar$, and $G$ to $1$.

Comment: @ DerekSeabrooke If you consider only **stable** hadrons then you only have the proton. A free neutron spontaneously decays. OK, neutrons are stable in nuclei. This still leaves very few cases of "two or three quarks not all of the same charge". When you start considering unstable hadrons, you have the charged $\pi$ mesons with combination of one quark and one antiquark of charges of the same sign $\bar d u$ or $\bar u d$ and the charged $K$’s. As G. Smith pointed out the most stable baryon made up of three identical (strange) quarks is the Omega, unstable but certainly a well known particle.